# Объясните назначение портов tomcat

Tags: tomcat

Помогите разобраться с назначением портов в tomcat:
Имеется приложение в tomcat, расположенное на сервере CentOS 7, в папке webapps лежит приложение, обслуживаемое этим tomcat-ом.

```
 netstat -tlpn | grep 'pid_tomcat'
```

выдает:

> ::ffff:127.0.0.0:8005
>   ::8009
>   ::8080
>   ::45978

За что какой порт отвечает?

Я знаю только, что `8080` это для обращения к приложению из браузера: `http://ip:8080/app`

А вот зачем нужны остальные я не разобрался.

Comment: Так частичное объяснение есть. Интересует "случайный" порт 45978 (он при каждом запуске другой)? И почему иногда при ./bin/shutdown случайный порт остается висеть? (Приходится глушить его через kill)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`8005` - shutdown порт
`8009` - [AJP connector](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/ajp.html) порт

Значения задаются в файле `$TOMCAT_HOME/confg/server.xml`, например:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />

    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t "%r" %s %b" />
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Comment: shutdown порт - т.е. при ./bin/shutdown - он связывается с этим портом?

Comment: Нет, при посылке на порт 8005 строки `SHUTDOWN` Tomcat вырубается в течении 10 секунд

Comment: Спасибо, за разъяснения

Comment: А можно пример `при посылке на порт 8005 строки SHUTDOWN`, а то на тесте попробовал через nc - ничего не вышло

Comment: [пример здесь](http://singcheong.blogspot.ru/2012/10/tomcat-shutdown-port-8005-remote.html)